# JS variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I know this question has been asked a lot and this is going to get flagged as duplicate, but I need the code because I can't get my head around any of it.
I have a variable x in my js file. I want that in my php file. Here's the messed up code that I have:
index.js-

```
var x=5;
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'form.php',
  data: {'variable': x },
});
```

form.php-

```
<?php $myval = $_POST['x'];
echo $myval;?>
```

Also, do I need to connect with the server first or something for the ajax call? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need the `?>` and are probably better off without it, might get new line of returned value as is.

Answer (score 5):

You're adding this POST body

```
['variable' => 5]
```

Why are you then requesting `$_POST['x'];`?
The index `x` is undefined and will throw a notice/error.

Something useful you can do (during development only), when you're unsure what is accessible in you're PHP code is dumping the required variable:

```
<?php 
   var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update @chris85. I'm still new to the formatting within SX.

Comment: Might want to look at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks for formatting options in the future. It was pretty well formatted already.

Comment: Hello people. The 'x' in there was a mistake. I'd written the correct code before and it still showed an "undefined index: variable" error.

Comment: Please verify that the correct PHP file is requested by the Ajax request. If so, check the available indexes with `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: doesn't work. It shows an array of the login data thats present in the same form.php file though. Maybe the stuff isnt referencing properly.

Comment: @NavyaNidhiSharma Are you using the browser console (e.g. Firebug)?

Answer (score 4):

In Ajax data you have sent `key:value`. So in PHP file you can access it by `$_POST['key']`.

Here your key is `variable` and value is `x which is 5`
 So you can access it by `$_POST['variable']`

Write it as below:-

```
<?php 
$myval = $_POST['variable'];
echo $myval; // output will be 5
?>
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I did use this code and it still shows the same error. Undefined index: variable.   
The code looks alright though. Everything is on my localhost. I have the src tag referring to the js file alright too. Can't figure out what might be the problem

Comment: Write this line and check output :- echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: doesn't work. It shows an array of the login data thats present in the same form.php file though. Maybe the stuff isnt referencing properly.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: variable in C:\xampp\htdocs\form.php on line 100
array(3) { ["submitLogin"]=> string(0) "" ["uname"]=> string(5) "navya" ["password"]=> string(8) "wrvwrvwr" }

Comment: I have a lot of code. Maybe I'm mixing stuff up. The code syntax (after the correction in key:variable) looks correct though right?

Comment: You are calling ajax on submit button. If you do that then your page is redirected to form action and your ajax will not work. So Do one thing. Submit your whole data via ajax. Set form action = ''#" to prevent redirection. Get your all data via javascript and sent it via ajax.

Answer (score 1):

This ajax call is like this form submit

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST"> 
<input type="text" name="variable" value="5">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then in your form.php you will do:

```
<?php 
myval = $_POST['variable'];
echo $myval; // output will be 5
?>
```